# Relational expression, with a table entry from a function with multiple results, without extra variable?

Tags: lua, lua-table

I want to compare the table entry that is returned by a function with a fixed string. It works if I first store the result in a variable as a list.
Why is it not possible as a one line expression. Is there a better way to do it?

```
-- similar to function provided by an API
local testFunction = function()
    return true, {name = "hans"}
end

--works
local a = {testFunction()}
if a[2].name=="hans" then
    --do something
end

--doesn't work
if {testFunction}[2].name=="hans") then
    --do something
end
```

Comment: `if ({testFunction()})[2].name=="hans" then`

Comment: Thank you very much, this worked. What is the reason for this behaviour? (So I won't have to ask again when encountering a different problem caused by this)

Comment: `{....}[2]` is not implemented in Lua syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Adding parentheses solves the issue

```
if ({testFunction()})[2].name=="hans" then
    --do something
end
```

Thank you Egor Skriptunoff for the comment